# SVG ViewBox breaks Zoom functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, zooming

I'm working on an svg floorplan layout that users should be able to zoom in and out of.

When I first coded it, the zooming feature worked, but the svg wasn't responsive to the container size. I added the viewbox property to make it responsive, but this interferes with the zoom feature - it zooms in even if you try to zoom out, and the zooming doesn't work the way it did before I added viewbox.

Here are 2 codepens demonstrating the issue:

#### Codepen 1

without viewbox - svg zooms correctly, but is not responsive to container size
https://codepen.io/nicole-dsouza/pen/WJVywK

the only difference is in the opening svg tag:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="100%" height="100%">
```

#### Codepen 2

with viewbox - svg is responsive, but doesn't zoom correctly
https://codepen.io/nicole-dsouza/pen/QrexyV

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 873 699">
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's causing the issue? I need the svg to be responsive and zoomable at the same time.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why did you put the [tag:d3.js] tag here? You're never using D3 to zoom, but a jQuery plugin instead. I just edited your question with the correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and height attributes, and use a viewbox instead. And wrap the svg in a responsive object wrapper. See https://codepen.io/vcurd/pen/bKEdQe

```
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewbox="0 0 890 150">
```

Comment: I removed width and height from both code samples, but it didn't make any difference